# Keeping UI Elements in UINavigationBar across different Views

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a few UIElements in my UINvigationBar on the main screen of my iPad app. Namely a few buttons and a UISearchbar.

I would like these items to remain in the UINavigationBar when ever a I push a new ViewController onto the navigation stack. At the moment I am not really sure how to do with, without setting up the nav bar over and over on each new screen. Also i am not sure where I would put the search bar logic so that it works on any screen.

An excellent example of what I am trying to do can be seen on eBays current iPad app.

How do I keep a "static" UINavigationBar on an iPad app and would I use a base view controller for the search maybe?

Would appreciate any feedback on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `UIViewController` that does all of the nav bar setup. Have all of your custom view controllers inherit from that view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking view controller containment would be the better way to go from here? If I took your approach, I would need delegates is every subview to know when the search bar was active and to use the buttons correct?

Comment: Yes, you could use a custom view controller container as well. You could use delegation as a pattern to inform the child view controllers, or KVO, or notifications.

Comment: Thanks. I really need it to act like a UINavigationController with push / pop VCs. I wish I could email eBay and ask them how they do it. Going to just have to experiment more to figure this out. Appreciate the insight.

Comment: Just an update: I tried subclass and it is MUCH closer to what I am after. However the buttons seems to fade in/out each time I got o a new VC. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I didn't think about that. Since a `UINavigationController` automatically animates it's VCs... another possible solution would be to subclass `UINavigationBar` and set that on your `UINavigationController` when you initialize it.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion - Just subclassing UIViewController and setting up the navBar and everything else I need in there and have all other VCs subclass that - it has turned out to be exactly what  I needed and works well - which is why I accepted the answer. Thanks for all the help!